# Playing local video .MOV file in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, video, uiwebview

Hi I am trying to play a local video in my UIWebView.

I don't think i am doing this right. It was easy before, because you can place a local video into the Mainbundle, and just name the html tags to be :

but now my video is stored in the documents directory/video folder/video.MOV

how do i get that.. in to the source("src:" attributes, for the html5 video?

```
NSString *videoHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div align=\"center\"><video src=\"%@\" controls=\"controls\"></video></div>", videoName];

    [cell.videoWebView loadHTMLString:videoHtml baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.documentsDirectoryPath]];
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay you could construct the URL like this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *videoFilePath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video folder/"];

NSString *videoHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div align=\"center\"><video src=\"%@\" controls=\"controls\"></video></div>", videoName];

[cell.videoWebView loadHTMLString:videoHtml baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoFilePat]];
```

Comment: I tried this in iOS 7 and it gives a whole bunch of errors like the one below, when the video starts playing. <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *videoPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath]];
[cell.videoWebView loadRequest:req];
```

Comment: I tried this in iOS 7 and it gives a whole bunch of errors like the one below, when the video starts playing.

<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.